# Does terracotta support adding a node during runtime?

Tags: java, terracotta

Can I add more terracotta instances during runtime, e.g. when RAM running low on the existing machines?

I am also not sure, if I understand the architecture of terracotta. Is the following correct?

A terracotta client is simply a web-app using the terracotta interface and libraries. It needs to be connected to a terracotta-server that manages multiple clients. If the application stores something in terracotta, it is stored like a normal object in its own JVM (providing fast access) and also magically shared among the other clients so they can access the same object if needed.

I'd like to use terracotta for session replication for an elastic cluster of app-servers (meaning there could be app-server-instances added/removed during runtime without interruption of services).

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK You can, but I have not done this myself.

Comment: Do you have more information on how it could be done? Maybe a link? Thanks

Comment: I would expect terracotta have such a link.  Can you ask them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work for Terracotta as a Software Engineer.

At this point, you can't add a node to a Terracotta Cluster dynamically. You'll need to shut down the cluster, add the new servers to your tc-config file and then restart the cluster.

As far as your understanding of the architecture goes, it's correct when seen from a 30,000 feet level. For sessions replication, I recommend that you look at our Sessions product.

http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.0/web-sessions